# How to show that the effect of one variable on the outcome is larger in one condition than the other?

Tags: lme4-nlme, interaction, post-hoc

I have the following lmer model:

```r
OFC_R = lmer(LexSemErr ~ ONsize_norm*Repeated_code + 
    Frequency_norm*Repeated_code + Concreteness_norm*Repeated_code + 
    ( 0 + Repeated_code | Word), data = nrm_reppriming_sim)
```

Briefly, one participant read 512 `Word`s that each had a fixed orthographic neighborhood size (`ONsize_norm`), lexical frequency (`Frequency_norm`) and concreteness (`Concreteness_norm`); these predictors were normalized before fitting the `model` (ie each variable had a mean = 0 and sd = 1). Finally, each word appeared in two conditions: repeated (`Repeated_code == 1`) or not (`Repeated_code == -1`). For each `Word` that was read, we collected an outcome called `LexSemErr`.

The model summary shows that all of these predictors were significant, and that all interactions with Rep_code were significant:

```r
> summary(OFC_R)
    Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method
 ['lmerModLmerTest']
    Formula: LexSemErr ~ ONsize_norm * Repeated_code + Frequency_norm * Repeated_code +      Concreteness_norm * Repeated_code + (0 + Repeated_code |  
        Word)
       Data: nrm_reppriming_sim
    
    REML criterion at convergence: 8725.8
    
    Scaled residuals: 
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
    -7.9400 -0.2586 -0.0139  0.4660  2.7100
    
    Random effects:
     Groups   Name          Variance Std.Dev.
     Word     Repeated_code   0.0     0.00
     Residual               297.7    17.25
    Number of obs: 1024, groups:  Word, 512
    
    Fixed effects:
                                     Estimate Std. Error        df  t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)                      146.9318     0.5392 1016.0000  272.520  < 2e-16 ***
    ONsize_norm                       15.3737     0.5400 1016.0000   28.470  < 2e-16 ***
    Repeated_code                   -125.5203     0.5392 1016.0000 -232.807  < 2e-16 ***
    Frequency_norm                    -1.6234     0.5411 1016.0000   -3.000  0.00276 **
    Concreteness_norm                  6.4622     0.5407 1016.0000   11.953  < 2e-16 ***
    ONsize_norm:Repeated_code        -15.1286     0.5400 1016.0000  -28.016  < 2e-16 ***
    Repeated_code:Frequency_norm       1.2949     0.5411 1016.0000    2.393  0.01689 *
    Repeated_code:Concreteness_norm   -3.2222     0.5407 1016.0000   -5.960 3.48e-09 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
    
    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                (Intr) ONsz_n Rptd_c Frqnc_ Cncrt_ ON_:R_ Rp_:F_
    ONsize_norm  0.000
    Repeated_cd  0.000  0.000
    Freqncy_nrm  0.000 -0.044  0.000
    Cncrtnss_nr  0.000 -0.015  0.000  0.066
    ONsz_nrm:R_  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
    Rptd_cd:Fr_  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.044       
    Rptd_cd:Cn_  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.015  0.066
    optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
    boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

I want to show that the effect of each predictor on the outcome is larger in the `Repetition_code == -1` condition than in the other `Rep_code == 1` condition; how do I do this?

---

What I tried so far:

I split the data by Repetition_code, and fit a different `lm` for each, like this:

```r
    # fit separate models for repeated and unrepeated
    repeated_items = nrm_reppriming_sim %>% filter(Repeated_code == 1)
    unrepeated_items = nrm_reppriming_sim %>% filter(Repeated_code == -1)
    lm_rep = lm(LexSemErr ~ ONsize_norm + Frequency_norm + 
                Concreteness_norm, data= repeated_items)
    lm_unrep = lm(LexSemErr ~ ONsize_norm + Frequency_norm + 
                  Concreteness_norm, data= unrepeated_items)
```

And then I show that the slopes for the predictors are bigger in one of the conditions than the other. Does that work?

```r
summary(lm_unrep)
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)        272.452      1.056 257.971  < 2e-16 ***
    ONsize_norm         30.502      1.058  28.836  < 2e-16 ***
    Frequency_norm      -2.918      1.060  -2.753  0.00611 **
    Concreteness_norm    9.684      1.059   9.144  < 2e-16 ***
 summary(lm_rep)
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
    (Intercept)        21.4114     0.2176  98.393   <2e-16 ***
    ONsize_norm         0.2450     0.2179   1.124    0.261    
    Frequency_norm     -0.3285     0.2184  -1.504    0.133
    Concreteness_norm   3.2400     0.2182  14.848   <2e-16 ***
```

Comment: They aren't bigger for *all* the variables; `Frequency_norm` is smaller (more negative) in the first case but `ONsize_norm` is larger in the first case.

Comment: Right - I meant bigger in absolute value.

Comment: Tables of coefficient estimates might not be the best option for this. Have you considered computing marginal effects. Take a look at [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) and [ggeffects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/index.html) and their vignettes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show that the effect of each predictor on the outcome is larger in the `Repetition_code == -1` condition than in the other `Rep_code == 1` condition; how do I do this?

You do *not* want to fit separate models, at each model throws away information from the data for the other situation and thus loses power.

You already have evaluated this, via the interaction coefficients for each of the other predictors with `Repeated_code`. The significance of each of the interaction coefficients means that there is a significant difference in slope for each of the other predictors between the two `Repeated_code` levels. The sign of the difference between `Repeated_code = -1`  and `Repeated_code = +1` is opposite the sign of the interaction coefficient. Your coding of `Repeated_code` as numeric at either -1 or +1 means you need to take some care in calculations, as the reported coefficients are for the (nonexistent) case of `Repeated_code = 0`; the magnitude of the difference between `Repeated_code = +1`  and `Repeated_code = -1` is twice the magnitude of the interaction coefficient.

For example, the coefficient (15.4) reported for `ONsize_norm` is the (theoretical) slope when `Repeated_code = 0`. The `ONsize_norm:Repeated_code` coefficient of -15.1 is the *difference* in slope for each unit *increase* of `Repeated_code` from 0. So the estimated slope for `ONsize_norm` at `Repeated_code = -1` is `15.4-(-15.1) = 30.5`, and at `Repeated_code = +1` is `15.4-15.1 = 0.3`. You can do similar calculations for the other continuous predictors. For corresponding confidence intervals, use post-modeling tools like those in the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) recommended by @dipetkov.

Note that these effects are dwarfed in magnitude by the major association of `Repeated_code` itself with outcome. The `(Intercept)` of 146.9 is the estimated outcome when all predictors including `Repeated_code` are at values of 0. With your centering of predctors, the `Repeated_code` coefficient of -125.5 means that, at mean values of the other predictors, the outcome is 272.5 at `Repeated_code = -1` versus 21.4 at `Repeated_code = +1`. You have to apply your understanding of the subject matter to decide whether the "statistically significant" associations of the other predictors are significant in practice.